# Geth stuck on blockNumber 0 while syncing is false on Ropsten

Tags: go-ethereum

I start geth with:

`geth --testnet`

It keeps constantly logging a variation of the following line:

`INFO [11-21|15:48:42] Imported new state entries               count=770  elapsed=1.795ms   processed=129338 pending=13126 retry=2   duplicate=0 unexpected=927`

My console attaches using:

`geth attach ipc:/home/faure/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc`

The following statements evaluate to `true`

```
> eth.blockNumber == 0
> eth.syncing == false
> net.peerCount > 0
```

I'd like `eth.blockNumber` to be up to date with the latest height so that my account has ETH. Since syncing is false, I'm not sure if I'm having trouble syncing or if I have finished syncing and for some reason the console can't find the blockchain data.

Comment: What does `admin.peers` returns? But your situation is odd, are you with the last version of geth v1.7.2/v1.7.3?. When syncing is stuck I'd restart geth, so it will try to connect again with bootnodes.